Problem with barcode detection zbar python
Im trying to detect and decode barcode. My program works well but with this one barcode i have a problem because of weird background. If you know what operations performed on images will be able to reveal this code i will be grateful. Im attaching a mentioned photo and part of the code responsible for barcode detection.
I tried some operations on image but i ve never had problem like that in past.
original image:

image after my basic operations:

gray = cv2.cvtColor(cropped_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
(h, w) = gray.shape[:2]
point1 = int(0.75 * w)
point2 = int(0.25 * h)
point3 = int(0.98 * w)
point4 = int(0.8 * h)
start_point = (point1, point2)
end_point = (point3, point4)
color = (255, 0, 0)
thickness = 2
gray = gray[point2:point4, point1:point3]
  


barcodes = decode(gray)
for barcode in barcodes:
    barcode_data = barcode.data.decode("utf-8")
    barcode_type = barcode.type
    
    print("Barcode Data:", barcode_data)
    print("Barcode Type:", barcode_type)
    (x, y, w, h) = barcode.rect
    cv2.rectangle(cropped_image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
  
    cv2.imshow('barcode', cropped_image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)


That image is too smudged to work.

here is the orginal image: https://imgur.com/a/x27PwN1

Threshold the original on black using cv2.inRange() rather than converting to grayscale and and otsu threshold. Or convert to gray and use simple threshold rather than otsu to threshold on pure black.

this might be workable, but not with the processing you did. that processing only made it worse. do not threshold. that ruins the signal. you need all the information there is to recover that code. this goes beyond a simple programming question. you should ask on https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ (and link the new question here)

@fmw42 I am pretty sure its good enough, not with this algorithm though @ filipoo635 try to first locate barcode (rectangle), then its orientation. Then it should be pretty straightforward - upsample if needed and find thresholding that makes sense.

@fmw42 i have algorithm that is able to find this barcode and draw a rectangle but im not sure what to do next with that. I cropped image and it didnt help.

@filipoo635. Please clarify what you need to do next.  You seem to have answered your question above.  So it is up to you now to ask another question or clarify your question above. Is something still not working above?

@fmw42 Im trying to decode this barcode by zbar. Maybe its possible to change some configuration of zbar

Sorry, I have no experience with zbar.  I was just trying to help you get a better image to process with it.
